# Unable to use the value of lat,long within payload that are related to any random city?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've written a script to grab the link of different properties from a webpage. The properties in that site show up when I perform a search using this keyword `toronto` exactly as you see in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HBmy.jpg).

[website link](https://www.realtor.ca/)

The script below can parse the link of different properties. However, what I can't understand is how I can use the value of lat, long other than copying from dev tools. Moreover, I used `toronto` in the search box but the following payload doesn't have that. I think the lat, long within payload represents the city.

```
import requests

link = "https://api2.realtor.ca/Listing.svc/PropertySearch_Post"

payload = {
    'ZoomLevel': '10',
    'LatitudeMax': '43.92411',
    'LongitudeMax': '-78.73025',
    'LatitudeMin': '43.49129',
    'LongitudeMin': '-80.02252',
    'Sort': '1-A',
    'PropertyTypeGroupID': '1',
    'PropertySearchTypeId': '1',
    'TransactionTypeId': '2',
    'Currency': 'CAD',
    'RecordsPerPage': '12',
    'ApplicationId': '1',
    'CultureId': '1',
    'Version': '7.0',
    'CurrentPage': '1'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.post(link,data=payload)
    for item in r.json()['Results']:
        print(item['RelativeDetailsURL'])
```

***How to use lat, long within payload that is related to any customized city?***

Answer (score 0):

Latitude and Longitude do represent the city.

```
'LatitudeMax': '46.88411',
'LongitudeMax': '-72.06525',
'LatitudeMin': '46.14629',
'LongitudeMin': '-70.57902',
```

Makes a square over the area of interest. So with the above values you get Quebec area as an example.